# Changing screens when navigating in bottomnavigation bar error

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hi Im new to flutter so please bear with me for asking too much nooby question. So I am currently developing an app, the first screen will be a Login/register screen then after a login or registration is directed, the actual **main app screen** is displayed I also set this screen as **stateless** and set a body to my `HomePage.dart` now on my `HomePage.dart` which is a **stateful** widget, which contains the **navigation bar** but for some reason, Im getting an error in

```
final List<Widget> _children [
    NavHome()
  ];
```

saying that the children is initialized. And Im confused since I followed the tutorial from medium exactly BUT with just a custom main screen (which appears after the main.dart)

the code for the actual **main app screen** is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

import 'home.dart';


class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

the code for **Home.dart** is below which says the children variable isnt initialized

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vmembershipofficial/screens/nav_home.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    static final String id = 'homepage';
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _currentTab = 2;
  final List<Widget> _children [
    NavHome()
  ];


  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentTab = index;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
        body: _children[_currentTab],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: onTabTapped,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _currentTab, //makes a new variable called current Tab
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 30.0),
              title: Text('Search', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
              title: Text('Favorites', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text('Home', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.message),
              title: Text('Messages', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              title: Text('Account', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

> NOTE: I just want the bottom navigation bar to change to the NavHome, or NavProfile when I tapped on different tabs. I just cant seem to find a way why the _children variable isnt initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there!

**What went wrong**

```
final List<Widget> _children [ // Missing = sign
   NavHome()
];
```

**What you can do**

Convert the code snippet above to:

```
final List<Widget> _children = [ // Add = sign here
   NavHome(),
   NavProfile(),
   // Add more screens here   
];
```

I created a simple app for you, which mocks your use case that you need to switch between `NavHome` and `NavProfile`.

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(ExampleApp());

class ExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Example App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String id = 'homepage';
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _currentTab = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    RedPage(),
    BluePage(),
  ];

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentTab = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _children[_currentTab],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _currentTab,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            title: Text(
              'Red',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text(
              'Blue',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RedPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BluePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have also noticed that you have 5 widgets in your bottom navigation bar, feel free to add placeholders so you won't get `RangeError` exception whenever you tap on tabs without the counterpart screen/s.

Hope this helps.

Comment: my my, my rookie mistake. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, happy to help!